# How do I pass an Activity via MethodChannel in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm making a Flutter app that needs to call a third party library (jar file provided).

The Java documentation for the third-party API object is created by calling something

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ThirdPartyAPI mAPI;

    private ThirdPartyAPICallbacks mCallbacks = new ThirdPartyAPICallbacks(){
        @Override
        public void Connected() {
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       mAPI = new ThirdPartyAPI(this, mCallbacks); // how do we do the equivalent in Flutter?
    }

}
```

How do I do this in Flutter?

I tried MethodChannel, but I don't know what to pass as the Activity instance to the ThirdPartyAPI constructor.

Comment: Do you just want to include it in your app, or write a re-usable plugin that can be used in many apps?

Comment: I just want to be able to call the 3rd-party API from my flutter app, then respond in my Flutter apps to any callbacks made by that API.

Comment: I understand, but the solution varies depending on the type of project: plugin or one off app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't transfer to `Activity` across the method channel. It only ever exists at the Java end. Instead it gets 'attached' to the Java end of the channel.

When creating a plugin (this is probably preferred as you can re-use it in different projects), make sure the plugin class also implements `ActivityAware`. Create stub implementation for the four methods required, in particular `onAttachedToActivity`.

For example:

```
public class ThirdPartyApiPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware {

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    Activity activity = binding.getActivity();
    mAPI = new ThirdPartyAPI(activity, mCallbacks);
  }
```

If not using a plugin, modify the `MainActivity` class as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation).

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "someChannelName";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    mAPI = new ThirdPartyAPI(this, mCallbacks);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            // TODO
          }
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give this a look? @RichardHeep
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870123/how-to-get-activity-from-java-in-flutter-plugin

Answer (score 2):

`MethodChannel` doesn't and will never allow to send something like an Activity.

The only types allowed are the following from the official [**DOCS**](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec):

[image: MethodChannel Types]

If you really need to send something to **Flutter**, you'd need to create a method on **Flutter** which will call Java/Kotlin side, then get anything important you need from that 3rd party API/Library/Etc and send that info back to **Flutter** using a `MethodChannel`.